# Schedule removal of activated login IP & activated client browsers

Tags: api, security

I want to force users to regularly go through the SMS login activation process by clearing down the activations list in Salesforce.

In the Salesforce configuration menu Setup>Security Controls>Activations it is possible to see a list of IP addresses and web browsers which have been recorded as part of the SMS or email activation process.

It is possible to remove entries from the list manually, but I would like to be able to schedule a clean up of this data weekly without needing to visit the configuration.

I have looked to see if the information is stored in a standard object, it doesn't seem so.
There doesn't seem to be any API support for this data either.

Does anyone have a suggestions of where I could look next to try and add this feature?

thanks :)

Comment: Did you have a security breach recently or...?

Comment: No, this has been requested by the client as part of the overall security model.  They don't want to use the 2-factor authentication app, SMS activation will be sufficient if we can get it to fire weekly.

Comment: Wow. My sympathies... hopefully seldom enough not to annoy the users.

Answer (score 3):

There's no API for this that I could find, but standard screen scraping might be possible, although the anti-click-jacking module that Setup employs would complicate the process. Selenium would be your easiest route, if you've an interal Java developer. I'd envision a server set up to run a Selenium "test" that performs the scraping for you. In the meantime, I'd suggest posting an idea on the Idea Exchange.